# Порядок таблиц при объединении с помощью join

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, sqlite3, join

У меня есть две таблицы `cards` и `sides`:

```
create table cards (card_id integer primary key asc);

create table sides (side_id integer primary key asc,
                    card_id integer,
                    side_text text,
                    foreign key (card_id) references cards(card_id));
```

Для каждой записи в таблице `cards` есть две записи в таблице `sides`.

Предположим, что вставлено две карточки. Нужен запрос, который вернет карточку с двумя сторонами:

```
card_id  side_id  side_text        side_id  side_text       
-------  -------  ---------------  -------  -------------
1        1        first question   2        first answer  
2        3        second question  4        second answer
```

Пытаюсь так:

```
select cards.card_id, 
       question.side_id, question.side_text, 
       answer.side_id, answer.side_text
from cards
join sides as question on question.card_id = cards.card_id
join sides as answer on answer.card_id = cards.card_id and answer.side_id != question.side_id
group by cards.card_id;
```

Результат такой:

```
card_id  side_id  side_text       side_id  side_text       
-------  -------  --------------  -------  ----------------
1        2        first answer    1        first question  
2        4        second answer   3        second question
```

Как поменять порядок объединенных таблиц?

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я вижу, вам нужно всего лишь заменить

```sql
answer.side_id != question.side_id
```

на

```sql
answer.side_id > question.side_id
```

Это при условии, что у вас `side_id` ответа всегда строго больше `side_id` вопроса.

Comment: При добавлении `side_id` ответа всегда больше, но потом карточки могут обменяться ответами или вопросами, поэтому не подходит к сожалению.

Comment: В таком случае ваш запрос невозможен, так как у сторон нету признака «ответственности».